# How to get folder by given message?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

Is there a way to find out in which folder message X lies?

`Office.context.mailbox.item` doesn't have that information nor methods to retrieve its folder, see API spec at
https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/preview/Office.context.mailbox.item

Already searched on GitHub and studied their docs. No clues. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any API in Office JS to get folder of a mail item. To get the folder of a mail item use EWS/REST APIs.

1. Get REST url using [Office.context.mailbox.restUrl](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox)
2. Get the REST token using [Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync([options], callback)](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox?product=outlook&version=v1.5)
3. Get the itemId using [Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox.item?version=v1.5#nullable-itemid-string)
4. Using the itemId get the message using [GetMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#GetMessage) REST API.
5. Parse the response and get the ParentFolderId from the [Message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#MessageResource) response.
6. Using the ParentFolderId get the folder using [GetFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#GetFolder) REST API.

Comment: Your scenario seems to be a very common use case, we can raise a request for parent folder information from Office JS at https://officespdev.uservoice.com

Comment: This is a painful solution. Should be much easier indeed. Plus I couldn't spot the ParentFolderId within Office.context.mailbox.item ... it's not there.

Comment: Note that the above steps do not work for anything in the Drafts folder, so yes, having better information available to us in a less painful way would be excellent